# Stop Execution of Databricks notebook after specific cell

Tags: azure-databricks

I Tried sys.exit(0)(Python code) and dbutils.notebook.exit() on Databricks notebook. But both the option didn't work.
Please suggest any other way to stop the execution of code after a specific cell in Databricks notebook.

Comment: raise exception?

Comment: @AlexOtt I Have tried this , but that is also not working. try:
  if(df.shape[0]==0 and df_1.shape[0]==0 and df_2.shape[0]==0):
    print('Stop the excution here')
    dbutils.notebook.exit('stop')
  else:
    pass
except:
  print('ex')

Comment: `dbuilts.notebook.exit()` is used when the notebook is called from another notebook, not when it's executed interactively. Just use `raise Exception("exit")` instead of it...

Comment: @AlexOtt Can you provide the code instead. That will be helpful.

Comment: I wrote it - it's just having the `raise`

Comment: @AlexOtt i tried this :  if(df.shape[0]==0):
raise Exception("exception"). But That didn't work. I believe that is what you were saying.

Answer (score 36):

`dbutils.notebook.exit()` does not work because you need to put the string argument, it fails silently without it. To make it work you should write something like:

```
dbutils.notebook.exit("whatever reason to make it stop")
```

Comment: while it is true that another answer shows the use of `.exit()`, what this answer adds is that if you do not pass a string argument, the call will fail silently. Perhaps this answer could have been a comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 7):

Just use this. And click on run all cell button on Databricks notebook. If the condition is satisfied then execution will be stopped. Worked for me.

`if (df.shape[0]==0): dbutils.notebook.exit('stop')`