# How to Exit Azure databricks Notebook while Job is running

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am executing azure databricks notebook and Keeping try catch for exception handling in that I want to exit notebook run when Exceptions meet true. I'm keeping notebook exit command but it is moving to next cell.

Below is my code and output when I executed notebook. Can you please check and help If I'm doing wrong in any place.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you run the notebook?

Comment: You can refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66275401/stop-execution-of-databricks-notebook-after-specific-cell

Comment: If you executed this notebook from a different notebook (using %run or dbutils.run) or job then dbutils.notebook.exit('') will work. If you run the notebook from the notebook itself (Eg: Run All Cells button), it will work. However, if you run the cells using 'Run All Above' or 'Run All Below', dbutils.notebook.exit('') will not work.